# How to put commas for every 3 digit in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, printf

I'm new to SQL and stack overflow, I wanted to ask, how to put commas after 3 number?

The result I get is `150444600000.0`, what I wanted is `150,444,600,000.0` so I can read the number easier.

Below attached the image syntax for reference

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szYk2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the function [`printf()`](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html):

```
SELECT printf('%,d.%01d', SUM(total_revenue * 30)) AS total_monthly_revenue
```

There is no need to cast to `float`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6fb0990e3184ea173d28ba10a0bc9b48).

Comment: thanks for the answer, didnt know there's printf function

Answer (score 0):

Please try this syntax

```
SELECT FORMAT(150444600000.0, 'C4')
```

Output

---

```
$150,444,600,000.0000
```

For more information check this link: [SQL Server Formats](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6124/sql-server-format-function-for-dates-numbers-and-sql-server-agent-dates/)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks, i found that too from the link. Anyway, i just found out that the 'format' function is not available on SQLite, do they really don't have it or it's on another kind of function? thanks

Comment: The question is about SQLite and not SQL Server.

Comment: dgrszombie315 and @forpas - SQLite was not clear in question, still i didn't get the idea why my answer was downvoted? I will try to improve in future let me know the reason.

Comment: @AshutoshRanjan your answer is about SQL Server only and does not work in SQLite. This question had/has the tag SQLite only.

Comment: very nice and helpfull.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT FORMAT(12134567.829, '#,#.00')

[image]

Comment: The question is about SQLite and not SQL Server.